# Using the Pervasive ADO.NET Provider with Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, ado.net, pervasive

I downloaded and installed the `Pervasive ADO.NET SDK v3.5` and am using the driver it comes with to connect to the database from within Visual Studio 2010.

However, when I create my Linq to SQL class and try to drag the tables into it, it says that Im using an unsupported provider. Does anyone know is there is a way around this or to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This driver only supports **Entity Frameworks**